# Stop media player using method in a service class

Tags: android, service, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming

i'm building an app to stream a radio from internet. Researching i found that for this i need to create a service because i want that the radio still playing when the app is minimized.

I created the service class and call it form my main activity, and i'm able to stream the audio, but now i want to implement a button in order to stop the streaming when the user open the app, so i bind my service to my activity and create a public method to stop the media player. This is my service class:

```
public class StreamClass extends Service implements    MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener{

MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
String URL ="http://rfcmedia.streamguys1.com/classicrock.mp3";
private IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();
private boolean prepared=false;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(URL);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.start();
    prepared=true;
}

public void StopRadio(){
    mMediaPlayer.stop();
}

public class MyBinder extends Binder{
    StreamClass getService(){
        return StreamClass.this;
    }
}
```

}

And this is my MainActivy:
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private SeekBar volumeSeekbar = null;
private AudioManager audioManager = null;
String URL = "http://rfcmedia.streamguys1.com/classicrock.mp3";
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
StreamClass streamClass = new StreamClass();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Intent i = new Intent(this, StreamClass.class);
    startService(i);
    bindService(i, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    ImageButton btnStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);

    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            streamClass.StopRadio();
        }

    });
}

private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        MyBinder myBinder =(MyBinder)service;
        streamClass=myBinder.getService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

    }
};
```

}

When i click on the stop button, i have the following error:
E/MediaPlayer: stop called in state 1
E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)

Seems that the mediaPlayer is not in the correct state for stop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The following line `StreamClass streamClass = new StreamClass();` gives you a brand new instance of your Service. The MediaPlayer in this new instance is not playing. You want to access the existing Service. Do so by using `startService()` with a specific Intent action from your activity. Evaluate the Intent action in `onStartCommand()` and call `stopRadio()` if necessary.

Comment: Ok i removed the StreamClass streamClass = new StreamClass() and should start the service again from the stop button? and sent and extra, let say intent.putExtra("Code", "Stop") and then evaluate this inside the service class?

Comment: Precisely. Using `startService()` will not restart the Service if it's already running. It will cause a call to `onStartCommand()` and then you can evaluate the Intent parameter of this method for details. If you find e.g. the String extra for key "Code" and its value is "Stop" then your Service simply can clean up if necessary and call `stopSelf()`